# OpenCart 2.2. How to show Stock per Option with Zero Stock also showing

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

We have worked out to show stock per option. http://www.vapour.me.uk/crazy-custard-flavour.html . Very pleased with that.

What we need now is when a "Product Option " is zero or less, it will display the stock status "2 to 3 Days" So customers can still buy that product option.

On Forum, it has been done for a earlier Opencart, but cannot find anything for 2.2. We are not scared of changing, coding or changing files.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You must show your code.
for example if you show stock per option this way:

```
<?php echo $product['option']['quantity']; ?>
```

You can change it to this:

```
<?php if($product['option']['quantity'] == 0){ ?>
    2 to 3 Days
<?php } else {
    <?php echo $product['option']['quantity']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

You need also edit you product in admin panel and set `Subtract Stock` to `No`, so your customers can see options with no stock and also can buy them.

[image]